Error in simple if else statement in Power Query
I have the following line written in m.
= Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each if [Count] mod 5 = 0 then 0 else 1)

The error I am getting is Expression.SyntaxError: Token 'then' expected.
This makes no sense, since the syntax is correct.
This is what I see:

Davide has the answer, but in the future you can use M language reference at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-function-reference to find the appropriate function and usage

Do you mean this?
= Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each if Number.Mod([Count],5) = 0 then 0 else 1)

